# Android Emulator Crashing in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working with Android Honeycomb.

I have created an AVD with default setttings for Android 3.0. But the emulator always crashes,even before the application loads. The console shows following error

```
[2011-03-08 19:15:12 - Emulator] 
[2011-03-08 19:15:12 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2011-03-08 19:15:12 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Anyone knows what causes this error.

Thanks.

**Update:** Now its is crashing for any configuration even in 2.2. The emulator just doesn't start. Is it something to do with Eclipse?

Comment: This is too less information to diagnose. I bet something went wrong with your installation. Re-install the SDK ?

Comment: What more can I provide? I tried creating another project for 2.2 version but same result. However it works with on Android Mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'v found that this is a permissions problem (usually in windows). If you start the AVD manager as Administrator outside of eclipse and then start, from it the emulator you want, you can now connect.

Answer (score 2):

For all who are facing this problem. There is one more case wherein the emulator may face problem. If you increase the device ram size too much. I believe  256 MB to 500MB it works fine but beyond you may face problem or in some cases the emulator doesn't load at all.

Comment: +1 - mine was running so slowly so i put it upto a gig on an 8gb system. This killed it completley so i reduced it to 500. Still runs like a 3 legged dog though :(

Answer (score 1):

My project runs on virtualbox with android x86 3.2 image (without sound) and on AVD 2.2 on Eclipse with sound but same project crashes on Eclipse's emulator 3.0. I think it is because of the .mp3 file that is played when activity is launched. I could only run Hello world activity on AVD 3.0 in eclipse so far